# Filtered items do not fit to div correctly

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to filter an array of products and the filtering works fine, the only problem is that the filtered products do not fit to div as the original products. I am assuming there is a problem with the css.

Here is how they originally look:
[image]

Here is the function that does the filtering:

```
const clickSkin=()=>{
      let filteredProductsClone=products.filter(product=>product.category == 'skin')
      setIsFiltered(true)
      setFilteredProducts(filteredProductsClone)
    }
```

Here is the products component:

```
{isFiltered == false && <Products items={products}/>}
        {isFiltered && <Products items={filteredProducts}/>}
```

Here is the container of the products:

```
const MainProductsContainer=styled.div`
width:100%;
height: 200vh;
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
position:relative;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
`
```

And here is how they look after filtering:
[image]

What would be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide more detail about how you'd like the second image to look?

Comment: I want it to look like the first one, the items should be in the white div (Main Product Container), not half in Main Product Container and half in the container above..